# Use literal numbers in Fin patterns

Tags: pattern-matching, literals, agda, pattern-synonyms

On one hand, I can use `#_` to construct `Fin`s from literals:

```
open import Data.Fin

data I'mFinnish : Set where
  Mk : Fin 5 → I'mFinnish

foo : I'mFinnish
foo = Mk (# 3)
```

On the other hand, I can use literals to pattern match on naturals:

```
open import Data.Nat

data I'mANatural : Set where
  Mk : ℕ → I'mANatural

open import Data.Bool
bar : I'mANatural → Bool
bar (Mk 3) = true
bar _      = false
```

My question is, can I, [on the gripping hand](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_the_gripping_hand), use literals when matching on `Fin`s? I.e., what can I do to approximate the following, invalid as-is, Agda code:

```
open import Data.Bool
bar′ : I'mFinnish → Bool
bar′ (Mk 3) = true
bar′ _      = false
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [literal overloading](http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.2/language/literal-overloading.html). Quoting documentation, the [Agda.Builtin.FromNat](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/data/lib/prim/Agda/Builtin/FromNat.agda) module provides a type class

```
record Number {a} (A : Set a) : Set (lsuc a) where
  field
    Constraint : Nat → Set a
    fromNat : ∀ n → {{_ : Constraint n}} → A

open Number {{...}} public using (fromNat)

{-# BUILTIN FROMNAT fromNat #-}
```

which allows to overload natural literals. An instance for `Fin` can be found at the former link too. And you can directly define an instance for `I'mFinnish`.

Comment: That looks promising, but I couldn't get it to work: https://gist.github.com/gergoerdi/ec95524e608aa0daebcceaf724fe20b4 still fails on the `Mk 3` pattern with "`suc` is not a constructor of the datatype `Fin`
when checking that the pattern `suc (suc (suc zero))` has type
`Fin (fromNat 5)`".

Comment: @Cactus, I guess, this gist belongs to the Agda issue tracker.